# Object B BELONGS to Object A

Tags: java

Im getting back into java development and want to make sure I have something clear. If someone says that class A and class B are both objects and that class B BELONGS to class A is that just another way of saying that Class B EXTENDS class A ?

To define a little further it seems to me like Object A will have multiple instances and that each instance of object A will have multiple instances of object B .

Comment: Looks like a *HAS-A* statement, not an *IS-A*, so it should be that A has a field of type B.

Comment: Define "BELONGS"... As I understand it, "B BELONGS to A" means "B IS A MEMBER (FIELD / ATTRIBUTE) of A", and thus, it is not a subclass

Comment: Also, "class A and class B are both objects" ->`class` roughly means a type, while `object` refers to an instance of a type. They are absolutely not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is not using standard vocabulary. He/She should use [IS-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) and `HAS-A` instead of `BELONGS`.

#### IS-A Relationship:

In object oriented programming, the concept of IS-A is a totally based on `Inheritance`, which can be of two types Class Inheritance or Interface Inheritance. It is just like saying "A is a B type of thing".

- This refers to inheritance or implementation.
- Expressed using keyword `extends`.

*For example:* Apple is a Fruit, Car is a Vehicle etc.

Inheritance is uni-directional.

For example House is a Building. But Building is not a House.

#### HAS-A Relationship:

`Composition`(HAS-A) simply mean use of instance variables that are references to other objects.

- Has-A means an instance of one class “has a” reference to an instance of another class or another instance of same class.
- It is also known as “composition” or “aggregation”.

*For example:* Maruti has Engine, or House has Bathroom.

[image]

Comment: In the instance of HAS-A is it permissible to have multiple instances of "Engine"